# Expiration date on product variation

Tags: 8, commerce

How can I set an expiration date on a product variation?

I am building a webshop and my goal is to have an expiration date on a product variation, meaning the after a scheduled date, the product would no longer be available to sell, so it would automatically unpublish. Also, vice versa, the product variation might have a publishing date.

Currently I am looking at [scheduler](https://www.drupal.org/project/scheduler), but that is for nodes, not for products. Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: i guess, you should create custom cron, retrieve product data and test on expiration date field and unpublish all products has expiration date in the past, and then configure it to be executed for example each day or less, if your products expire fast, i think there is no contrib module for this take a look https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce/issues/3097086

Comment: @NeonBlank Please refrain from asking `What's the best...`. As that depends who you ask, and also what's "best" may vary per project requirements.

Answer (score 0):

#### [Job Scheduler](https://www.drupal.org/project/job_scheduler)

Provides an API to schedule jobs. Where you can programmatically unpublish product variation in worker callback.

Simple example:

> ```
> // Declare scheduler.
>
>   function example_cron_job_scheduler_info() {
>     $schedulers = [];
>     $schedulers['example_unpublish'] = [
>       'worker callback' => 'example_unpublish_nodes',
>     ];
>     return $schedulers;
>   }
>
> // Add a job.
>
>   $job = [
>     'name' => 'example_unpublish',
>     'type' => 'story',
>     'id' => 12, // must be unique
>     'crontab' => * 3 * * 0, // Every Sunday at 3 AM
>     'periodic' => TRUE, // set to false if you want to just run once.
>   ];
>   $service = \Drupal::service('job_scheduler.manager');
>   $service->set($job);
>
> // Work off a job.
>
>   function example_update_users_total(\Drupal\job_scheduler\Entity\JobSchedule $job) {
>     // Do stuff.
>   }
> ```

There is more examples & info in the [READ.ME](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/job_scheduler/-/blob/8.x-3.x/README.txt), so read it.

---

#### [Ultimate Cron](https://www.drupal.org/project/ultimate_cron)

Provides a UI where you can schedule all the cron jobs. You can implement your own [hook_cron](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!core.api.php/function/hook_cron/8.2.x) and then schedule it using Ultimate Cron.

[image]